# Crystals in piezoelectricity

Tags: crystals, piezoelectric

I was reading about piezoelectricity and crystals and found such a statement (on Wikipedia) :  For example, a 1 cm3 cube of quartz with 2 kN (500 lbf) of correctly applied force can produce a voltage of 12500 V.

Which formula was used to calculate that value?

I've seen this formula:

$D=dT+ϵE $

and when material is not connected to circuit it can be assumed that $D=0$. From that $E$ can be obtained and then voltage from $V=EL$. Is that true? Could someone guide me through the calculations to obtain the result 12500V from one cubic centimetre of quartz?

Comment: Did you take a look at [Fundamentals of piezoelectricity](https://www.researchgate.net/file.PostFileLoader.html?id=55e82f0761432518d08b4596&assetKey=AS%3A273845112508416%401442301171103) - it's a pretty comprehensive description of the equations that govern piezoelectric behavior.

Comment: Also - a bit easier to follow - [this link](http://www.piceramic.com/piezo-technology/fundamentals.html)

Comment: To stop you from developing the wrong intuition: the voltage has nothing to do with the volume, for the most simple case (which would be a gross oversimplification for any application) it's the electric field that will scale with a strain, but not in a linear fashion. If you are in need of a precise high voltage, piezo-ceramics are not the way to go, an electronic circuit would be.

Comment: @CuriousOne makes an interesting point: for a given pressure, the thickness of the sample is irrelevant: a thinner sample has a higher strain, and thus a higher field - but the voltage is field times thickness, and therefore independent of sample thickness. However, there is a dependence on area (for constant force) so shape of the sample does matter somewhat.

Comment: @Floris: I hope I got it right... I just don't want the OP to extract an incorrect intuition about how these materials behave from a poorly formulated example. Creating a (near) homogeneous strain from a mechanical force is quite an engineering challenge, if one looks at the design of precision strain gauges and other technical piezoelectric sensors and actuators... it's amazing what can be done with these materials, if used right, but using them "right" is absolutely non-trivial.